# Why does Capistrano deployment fail at assets:precompile without error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, yarnpkg, webpacker

*I've tried everything I could think of, but I can't get deployment to work.*

The app needs to deploy to a VPS hosted by Alwaysdata and running ruby 2.6.2, using Capistrano for deployment.
It's a Rails 6.0.2.2 application, using webpack for JS and sprockets for legacy scripts, all images and CSS.

```
# On local machine (MacOS)

$ bundle exec cap production deploy
00:00 git:wrapper
00:01 git:check
00:03 deploy:check:directories
00:03 deploy:check:linked_dirs
00:03 deploy:check:make_linked_dirs
00:05 git:clone
00:06 git:update
00:08 git:create_release
00:10 deploy:set_current_revision
00:10 deploy:symlink:linked_files
00:12 deploy:symlink:linked_dirs
00:18 deploy:config:bundler
00:20 bundler:install
00:20 deploy:assets:precompile
#<Thread:0x00007fb35ba959f0@/Users/Goulven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
/Users/Goulven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status=': rake exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Command::Failed)
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written

  INFO [3def24f1] Running bundle exec rake assets:precompile as vtcontrol@ssh-vtcontrol.alwaysdata.net

 DEBUG [3def24f1] Command: cd /home/www/app/releases/20200409174918 && ( export NODE_ENVIRONMENT="production" RAILS_ENV="production" RAILS_GROUPS="" ; bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
```

Running the last command locally or on the server does not produce any errors, only warnings:

```
# On production server:

$ cd /home/www/app/releases/20200409174918 && ( export NODE_ENVIRONMENT="production" RAILS_ENV="production" RAILS_GROUPS="" ; bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
yarn install v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.10.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.62s.
```

Hypothesis I've thought of:

1. Running out of RAM. Happens mainly with Digital Ocean, provider excludes that possibility, and anyway it would not compile when sshing to the server.
2. An issue with `node` vs `nodejs`. This used to nag me but it no longer happens, at first because I used sprockets only and added the `mini_racer` gem, which packages node for ExecJS, then because I included Bootstrap using webpacker instead of Sprockets, thus removing the dependency on `autoprefixer-rails` which [errors out when an old version of nodejs is present alongside node](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails/issues/144).
3. Capistrano incorrectly interpreting yarn/webpacker warnings for failures. I extracted Bootstrap into its own app/javascripts/bootstrap.js because webpacker complained that the generated JS was too large, so this can be ruled out. Yarn complains about unmet peer dependencies but these are dev dependencies, I don't think it should matter. **This might be the problem, but how can I test that?**
4. Anything else I should try? Could using webpack and sprockets cause conflicts in production for instance? It works fine in development, and the generated assets should not overwrite one another.

---

Here are the relevant portions of my Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'

group :production do
  # Used to load env vars from an .env file during deploy
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.13.0', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.4', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.6', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails-console', require: false
end
```

And finally the relevant portion of my `Capfile` and `deploy.rb`:

```
# Capfile

require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/rails/console'
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load
```

```
# config/deploy.rb

# Setup bundler
# Unset capistrano/bundler default flags because Bundler has deprecated them
set :bundle_flags,      '--quiet'
set :bundle_path,       nil
set :bundle_without,    nil
before 'bundler:install', 'deploy:config:bundler'

# Remove gems no longer used to reduce disk space used
# This command requires loading capistrano/bundler in Capfile
after 'deploy:published', 'bundler:clean'

# Skip migration if files in db/migrate were not modified
# This command requires loading capistrano/rails in Capfile
set :conditionally_migrate, true

# Rails app server manages the database
set :migration_role, :app

# Defaults to nil (no asset cleanup is performed)
# If you use Rails 4+ and you'd like to clean up old assets after each deploy,
# set this to the number of versions to keep
set :keep_assets, 2
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: regarding the yarn warning about fsevents not compatible with Linux, I see this on every deployment but my asset compilation (sprockets and webpacker) always succeeds. I don't believe this is your problem.

Comment: Thanks @LesNightingill, I was wondering about that. Apparently it's yet another issue caused by Capistrano having a completely different environment from a regular SSH user, which doesn't play nicely with the way tools are installed on this VPS architecture.

Comment: on the app that I work on, Capistrano uses my dev machine's ~/.ssh/config file, exactly the same as I do when I connect to the server by SSH. At least for me, the Capistrano SSH environment is the same as I use. What makes you think that it's using a different environment? Since I haven't configured any of Cap's ssh options, this seems to be the default behaviour.

Comment: To clarify, if you run it manually on the server it produces warnings but it does actually precompile the files? So it works over terminal based SSH but not via capistrano?

Comment: @2called-chaos Yes, when I run commands manually on the production server things run fine, warnings put aside. However when I run `cap production deploy` the `assets:precompile` task fails, and does not give any useful information except that the previous task finished okay. It's likely [Capistrano's non-interactive session handling](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/) playing badly with the peculiarities of the hosting provider…

Comment: @LesNightingill The difference I see is that ENV variables are unavailable to Capistrano. Since hosting is a done on a VPS, and customers can host more than one website/app in their environment, ENV vars are loaded by the server but not available to SSH sessions. That's why I had to duplicate them in a `.env.production` file and load them using `Dotenv.load`, otherwise Rails console could not connect to the database or do anything useful. I was able to set some useful options in `deploy.rb` using `set :default_env, { NODE_ENVIRONMENT: 'production' }`.

Comment: What is your capistrano log level? Suggest `set :log_level, :debug`. I think this will produce a log file that might have more info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, after days of trying everything I could think of I tried something I'd already tested but with the correct syntax this time, I guess, because it works now.

Here is what I needed to add to Capistrano's config file to ensure Yarn was available when deploying:

```rb
# In deploy.rb
# Add or adjust default_env to append .npm-packages to $PATH:
set :default_env, {
   PATH: '$HOME/.npm-packages/bin/:$PATH',
   NODE_ENVIRONMENT: 'production'
}
```

Explanation: VPS users are allowed to install binaries like Yarn "globally" (using `npm install --global yarn`). Under-the-hood the binary is installed in `$HOME/.npm-packages/bin`, and this folder is added to the `$PATH` for interactive/login shell sessions. Since Capistrano does its utmost to NOT pick up this, we have to force-feed the updated `$PATH` in `deploy.rb`.

Comment: I added your code in `config/deploy/staging.rb`  to define my ENV as staging  `NODE_ENVIRONMENT: 'staging'`
then i used the command `RAILS_ENV=staging bin/webpack` then the issue fixed

Comment: for rails 7 using esbuild and my yarn path `~/.npm-global/bin/yarn` this `PATH: '$HOME/.npm-global/bin/:$PATH' did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I had the same error and it turned out to be a memory issue. For anyone with the same issues, check if you ran out of memory with `free -m` during compilation. If you ran out you'll see something like `-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory`.

I'm using Digitalocean and my solution was to add swap space: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04