# Rails 6 Capistrano deploy is failing even though application works fine when it is started manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

So this application works perfectly fine when I deploy it to Heroku

I am trying to deploy this to a VM (a plain ubuntu droplet on digital ocean)

Have set up Capistrano as expected.
Am unable to figure out where this error is possibly coming from

```
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@<IP ADDRRESS>: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written
```

The Capistrano deploy logs are as follows:

```
00:21 deploy:assets:precompile
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
#<Thread:0x00007ff9d8ba40f8 /Users/josh.kurien/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    13: from /Users/josh.kurien/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
    12: from /Users/josh.kurien/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `run'
    11: from /Users/josh.kurien/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `instance_exec'
    10: from /Users/josh.kurien/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.6.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:67:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     9: from /Users/josh.kurien/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:92:in `within'
     8: from /Users/josh.kurien/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.6.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:68:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/josh.kurien/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:100:in `with'
     6: from /Users/josh.kurien/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.6.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:69:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
     5: from /Users/josh.kurien/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:80:in `execute'
     4: from /Users/josh.kurien/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `create_command_and_execute'
     3: from /Users/josh.kurien/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `tap'
     2: from /Users/josh.kurien/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
     1: from /Users/josh.kurien/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:170:in `execute_command'
/Users/josh.kurien/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status=': rake exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Command::Failed)
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written
    1: from /Users/josh.kurien/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/josh.kurien/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as deploy@<IP ADDRRESS>: rake exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@<IP ADDRRESS>: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written


Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@<IP ADDRRESS>: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written


** DEPLOY FAILED
```

Tried running the last command manually (as shown in debug logs)

```
cd /home/deploy/mark_antony/releases/20201201034511 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.7.1" RAILS_ENV="production" RAILS_GROUPS="" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
```

and this works perfectly fine.
When i try to run this build on the server manually, that works too

Need some help please

This is my `deploy.rb`:

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock "~> 3.14.1"

set :application, "mark_antony"
set :repo_url, "git@gitlab.com:browneinstitute/mark.git"

# Default branch is :master
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/#{fetch :application}"

append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', '.bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads'

set :keep_releases, 5

append :linked_files, "config/master.key"
```

Side Note: I manually made a new `current` symlink to a release directory that was created in this manner to see if nginx is able to serve the webpage.
And it is able to

Comment: Can you post your `deploy.rb` file as well? It does seem to be an issue with capistrano not managing to connect over SSH

Comment: Added it @DanielSindrestean

Comment: did the answer below help?

Comment: just figured it out, thanks for the help @DanielSindrestean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured this always failed at precompile assets and the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61210930/2358326

helped solve the issue, except I had to add a slightly different value for the path

```
# add in deploy.rb

set :default_env, {
    PATH: '$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/bin/:$PATH',
    NODE_ENVIRONMENT: 'production'
}
```

this was because running `$ which yarn` on the VM returned the following:

```
/home/deploy/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/bin/yarn
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but you can add to the answer '#add in deploy.rb'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add your ssh again, try this
`ssh-add`, in your console then try to deploy again.

Comment: Thank you for that, but this did not help

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you are missing a few key configurations in your `deploy.rb` without which you can't connect to your droplet.

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock "~> 3.14.1"

server 'YOUR_DROPLET_IP',
roles: [:web, :app, :db],

set :user,  'deploy'
set :application, "mark_antony"
set :repo_url, "git@gitlab.com:browneinstitute/mark.git"

# Default branch is :master
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/#{fetch :application}"

append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', '.bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads'

set :keep_releases, 5
# This might not be needed. If needed make sure to provide the correct path to your ssh key
set :ssh_options,     {
                        forward_agent: true,
                        user: fetch(:user),
                        keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa)
                      } 

append :linked_files, "config/master.key"
```

Comment: nope, this did not help either.. I actually had a `production.rb` file for deployment config for it, some of what you wrote was in there, the rest i added.

Initially it failed with unable to find rails secret (so i copied the `production.key` into the shared configs folder). 
and now we are back at errors that look like
```o: rake exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!```